# Android Layout complex buttons

Tags: android, image, button, onclick, overlap

Imagine if you will a layout that contains a circle within an elipse.  The top and bottom of the elipse touch the top and bottom of the circle, giving 3 segments.  The left and right segments of the elipse overlap the edges of the circle.  - So what I have is something like this (A(B)C).  If you drew a line from the top of the right most point of A to the bottom right most point of A, it woudl divide directly down the centre of B

I would like the 3 segments to work as independant buttons.  How can I acheive this?

I was thinking of using this method:  [Android Images with clickable areaa](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/)

However, will this be accurate enough along the edges?

Is there any other way of doing this that doesn't rely on simply squaring off the buttons?

Can Android click events ignore transparency?  So, if I had the segments as seperate images, overlapped, I could only register a click on coloured areas of each image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I tried and succeeded in using the hidden colour overlay method,linked in my first post.  This worked really well and is a very effective piece of coding

I then decided after many hours work I didn't like that particular layout and went down a more traditional design!  Oh well...living and learning!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to define that as an XML layout... it is not possible, but you can create your own custom view and override [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) to detect the touch and make whatever calculation you want to find out where the event happened.

To create your custom view, you can make it a subclass or Button if that helps...